# Getting ERROR Connection not open CLOSED when composing Futures using vertx-jooq-classic-reactive: 5.0.1

Tags: java, postgresql, vert.x, jooq

I have an issue when multiple Futures are being composed in order to perform **update** *Book* table and **insert/delete** certain rows in intermediate tables _Category_Book_ and _Author_Book_ since *Book* is connected with Many-To-Many relationship with Author and Category. Error message that I get in console is:

> ERROR com.ns.vertx.pg.BookJooqQueries - Error, something failed in deleteCategoryBookFuture.compose(..)! Cause: io.vertx.core.VertxException: Connection not open CLOSED

Also, I am using mixture of DAO instances and *execute()* method on instance of *ReactiveClassicGenericQueryExecutor* class. This is [repo link](https://github.com/nixos89/VertxPgReactiveJOOQ/blob/book_CRUD/vertx-pg-reactive-jooq/src/main/java/com/ns/vertx/pg/BookJooqQueries.java) to my class where I am getting this error and this is [HttpVerticle](https://github.com/nixos89/VertxPgReactiveJOOQ/blob/book_CRUD/vertx-pg-reactive-jooq/src/main/java/com/ns/vertx/pg/HttpVerticle.java) where routes, DAOs and other configuration is taking place for my RESTful web services.

I don't know if there is a possibility that I've "over-composed" Future instances and that's what's causing this error, but as I understood composition is used when certain operations (*Insert/Delete/Update*) need to be performed in sequential order and all have to succeeded.

Libraries I am using:
**Vert.x version:** 3.8.2
**vertx-jooq-classic-reactive**: 5.0.1
**postgresql**: 42.2.2 (Postgres DB is version 11.7 on my machine)

NOTE: I have these changes made in my **book_CRUD** branch, not to be mistaken with **master** (as I don't want to merge these not fully functional changes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've (to be more honest [@jklingsporn](https://github.com/jklingsporn)) managed to find a solution a solution to fix issue. Problem was that (as much as I understood) is to compose not Future instances, but there right-hand side values (that is method invocations). For example, I had my code written like this:

```
 Set<Long> deleteCategoryIdsSet = HashSet();
    Future<Integer> insertBCFuture = categoryBookDAO.insert(bookCategories);
    Future<Integer> deleteCategoryBookFuture = queryExecutor.execute(dsl -> dsl
                        .deleteFrom(CATEGORY_BOOK)
                        .where(CATEGORY_BOOK.BOOK_ID.eq(Long.valueOf(bookId)))
                        .and(CATEGORY_BOOK.CATEGORY_ID.in(deleteCategoryIdsSet)))
    Future<Integer> retVal = insertBCFuture.compose(res -> deleteCategoryBookFuture)
                   .setHandler(finalResRetVal -> {
                        // handle 'finalResRetVal'
..});
```

...and changed it to this as @jklingsporn suggested:

```
return queryExecutor.execute(dsl -> dsl
                        .deleteFrom(CATEGORY_BOOK)
                        .where(CATEGORY_BOOK.BOOK_ID.eq(Long.valueOf(bookId)))
                        .and(CATEGORY_BOOK.CATEGORY_ID.in(deleteCategoryIdsSet)))
                    .compose(res -> categoryBookDAO.insert(bookCategories));
```

In that (solved) way Future code [does not get magically delayed](https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq/issues/150#issuecomment-621104396) and error doesn't show up and deletes and inserts are successfully performed.